# RoutePrefixAttribute in ASP.NET 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-core, dnx

I've started a new Web API 2.0 project in ASP.NET 5. I try to create custom RoutePrefixAttribute class but I get this error

```
The type or namespace name 'RoutePrefixAttribute' could not be found 
(are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)   {ProjectName}.DNX Core 5.0
```

Should I use some other class instead?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

There is indeed no `RoutePrefixAttribute` in MVC 6. Applying a `[Route]` attribute on a controller will now act as a route prefix:

```
[Route("api/[controller]/[action]")]
public class ProductsController : Controller
{
    [Route("{id:int}")]
    public JsonResult Details(int id)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

This will match `api/Products/Details/42`.

Also see [this blogpost](http://www.strathweb.com/2015/01/asp-net-mvc-6-attribute-routing-controller-action-tokens/) by Filip W.